# call with parameters, that will be parsed from a single parameter

Tags: c++, c++17, crtp

My goal is to create a callable (`Derived` in the example), that has a list of parameters. It will be called with a single parameter, that is used to parse the values of the parameter list.

My current attempt is structurally similar to a kind of binding mechanism. It looks like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

// this is a helper meta function
template<typename FunctionType, int ParameterCount> struct parameter_type;
template<typename Ret, typename FirstParam, typename ... MoreParams>
struct parameter_type<Ret(FirstParam, MoreParams...), 0> {
    using type = FirstParam;
};
template<typename Ret, int ParameterCount, typename FirstParam, typename ... MoreParams>
struct parameter_type<Ret(FirstParam, MoreParams...), ParameterCount>  {
    using type = typename parameter_type<Ret(MoreParams...), ParameterCount - 1>::type;
};


// here comes the base with CRTP to call the Derived operator()()
template<typename Derived, typename ... Params> struct Base;

template<typename Derived> struct Base<Derived> {};

template<typename Derived, typename FirstParam, typename ... Params>
struct Base<Derived, FirstParam, Params...> :
    public Base<Base<Derived, FirstParam, Params...>, Params...> {
    private:
        FirstParam first_param_;
    public:
        Base(const FirstParam& first_param, Params& ... params):
            Base<Base<Derived, FirstParam, Params...>, Params...>{params...},
            first_param_{first_param} {};

        template<typename PrefixParamT>
        int operator()(
            typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<PrefixParamT, 
                                                        typename parameter_type<Derived, 0>::type>::value,
                                    typename std::remove_reference<PrefixParamT>::type>::type&& prefix,
            Params ... params) {
            // actually we parse first_param from prefix here
            (*static_cast<Derived*>(this))(std::forward(prefix),
                                           first_param_,
                                           params...);
        }
};

// we use that to create various callables like this
struct Derived : public Base<Derived, int, const std::string&, double> {
    Derived(int a, const std::string& b, double c) :
        Base<Derived, int, const std::string&, double>{a, b, c} {};

    int operator()(const std::string& t, int a, const std::string& b, double c) {
        // her comes our business logic
    }

    // this is necessary to make the basic call operator available to 
    // the user of this class.
    int operator()(const std::string&);
};

// they should be usable like this
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Derived d{1, argv[0], 0.5};

    // call the most basic operator()(). 
    // here all the values from argv[1] should be parsed and converted
    // to parameters, that we pass to the most derived operator()()
    d(argv[1]);
}
```

Of course, this will not compile, because `typename parameter_type<Derived, 0>::type>` can not be determined with `Derived` being an incomplete type. I understand that, but I have not yet managed to come up with an alternative implementation.

If course I could leave out the check for convertibility in the example without losing any functionality, just some clarity in compiler messages. In the my actual code, there are different overloads of `operator()()`, that should be picked based on the signature of `Derived::operator()()`. Therefore I'd need checks like that.

Is there a different approach? My goal is to make the callables like `Derived` as simple as possible. We'll have a lot of them in future with different signatures. That is exactly the reason, why I try to avoid to parse `prefix` inside `Derived::operator()()`.

## Solution

*For the benefit of future readers of this question.*

Thanks to the answer provided by @Yakk, I came up with a solution. This is still example code and will need more elaborate type traits checks in the `parse_params_chooser<>` templates to enable other callables, than free functions as well. But I think, the road is paved now and it should simply work like that.

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>
#include <experimental/tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

// basic machinery
template <typename Derived, typename ResultType, typename ... Params> struct parse_params_t;

template<typename Derived, typename ResultType, typename FirstParam, typename ... Params>
struct parse_params_t<Derived, ResultType, FirstParam, Params...> :
    public parse_params_t<parse_params_t<Derived, ResultType, FirstParam, Params...>, ResultType, Params...> {
    private:
        typename std::remove_reference<FirstParam>::type first_param_;
    public:
        parse_params_t(const typename std::remove_reference<FirstParam>::type& first_param, Params&& ... params):
            parse_params_t<parse_params_t<Derived, ResultType, FirstParam, Params...>, ResultType, Params...>{std::forward<Params>(params)...},
            first_param_{first_param} {};

        using parse_params_t<parse_params_t<Derived, ResultType, FirstParam, Params...>, ResultType, Params...>::parse;

        template<typename PrefixParamT>
        auto parse(const PrefixParamT& prefix, const Params& ... params) -> ResultType {
            return static_cast<Derived*>(this)->parse(prefix, first_param_, params...);
        }
};

template<typename Derived, typename ResultType, typename LastParam>
struct parse_params_t<Derived, ResultType, LastParam> {
    private:
        LastParam last_param_;
    public:
        parse_params_t(const LastParam& last_param):
            last_param_{last_param} {};

        template<typename PrefixParamT>
        auto parse(PrefixParamT&& prefix) -> ResultType {
            return static_cast<Derived*>(this)->parse(std::forward<PrefixParamT>(prefix), last_param_);
        }
};


// put things together in a last derived type
template <typename ResultType, typename ... Params>
struct parse_params_helper : public parse_params_t<parse_params_helper<ResultType, Params...>, ResultType, Params...> {
    parse_params_helper(Params&& ... params):
        parse_params_t<parse_params_helper<ResultType, Params...>, ResultType, Params...>{std::forward<Params>(params)...} {};

    using parse_params_t<parse_params_helper<ResultType, Params...>, ResultType, Params...>::parse;

    template<typename PrefixParamT>
    auto parse(const PrefixParamT& prefix, const Params& ... params) -> ResultType {
        return {params...};
    }
};


// choose parser depending on handler parameter types.
template <typename PrefixParamT, typename Handler> struct parse_params_chooser;

template <typename PrefixParamT, typename ... Params>
struct parse_params_chooser<PrefixParamT, int(Params...)> {
    static auto parse(int (handler)(Params...), Params&& ... params) {
        return [helper = parse_params_helper<std::tuple<Params...>, Params...>{std::forward<Params>(params)...},
                handler](PrefixParamT&& prefix) mutable -> int {
            return std::experimental::apply(handler, std::tuple_cat(helper.parse(prefix)));
        };
    }
};

template <typename PrefixParamT, typename ... Params>
struct parse_params_chooser<PrefixParamT, int(PrefixParamT, Params...)> {
    static auto parse(int (handler)(PrefixParamT, Params...), Params&& ... params) {
        return [helper = parse_params_helper<std::tuple<Params...>, Params...>{std::forward<Params>(params)...},
                handler](PrefixParamT&& prefix) mutable -> int {
            return std::experimental::apply(handler, std::tuple_cat(std::make_tuple(prefix), helper.parse(prefix)));
        };
    }
};

// create a nice free function interface to trigger the meta programm
template <typename PrefixParamT, typename Handler, typename ... Params>
auto parse_params(Handler& handler, Params&& ... params) {
    return parse_params_chooser<PrefixParamT, Handler>::parse(handler, std::forward<Params>(params)...);
}


// now we can use that to create various callables like this
auto handler(std::string t, int a, std::string b, double c) -> int {
    // her comes our business logic
    std::cout << "handler: " << t << " " << a << " " << b << " " << c << std::endl;
}

auto other_handler(int a, std::string b, double c) -> int {
    // more business logic
    std::cout << "other_handler: " << a << " " << b << " " << c << std::endl;
}

// they should be usable like this
auto main(int argc, char** argv) -> int {
    auto h = parse_params<std::string>(handler, 1, argv[0], 0.5);
    auto g = parse_params<std::string>(other_handler, 2, std::string(argv[0]) + " blabla", 1.5);

    // call the lambda, that will parse argv[1] and call the handler
    h(argv[1]);
    // call the lambda, that will parse argv[2] and call the handler
    g(argv[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `std::tuple` and `std::apply`.

Use `Ts...` expansion in an initializer list to build the arguments in a specific order.  Maybe use aligned storage or optionals to make it easy, or construct and assign if lazy.

Possibly pass in a compile-time or run-time index and the type to the parsing code.

So derived should read like:

```
struct bob : auto_parse< bob, void(int, std::string, double) >{
  int parse( std::string_view& data, size_t arg_index, tag_t<int> ) { return {}; } // actually parse
  // optional!  If missing default parser used.
  // etc
  void execute( int x, std::string const& s, double d ) const { /* code */ }
};
```

I would avoid the ambiguous `operator()` bit.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I am not sure, what you meant with using `std::tuple` and `std::apply`, but you put me on a new track, that looks promising now. If it works out, I'll post the solution here as an answer for everyone who searches. BTW.: I chose to use `operator()`, because the components should not only be restricted to classical objects. I also want to be able to use lambdas or even free functions as components - at least with the standard signature. If it works out, the new idea might even enable the parameter parsing for these as well:-)

Comment: @cdonat have a lambda not be a.  Wrap the call to `()` in an execute.  [`std::apply`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) takes a callable and a tuple, and unpacks the tuple to do the call.  Parse your args into a tuple instead of a bunch of member variables.

Comment: Ah, I see. Obviously my example was too simplifying. In the actual code, the member variables don't store actual parameter values, but instructions for the parser. The parameter values are then determined by parsing the prefix, while the parser interprets those instructions. Think of it like e.g. `auto d = Derived{std:.regexp{"[0-9]*"s}, std::regexp{"[^0-9.]*"s}, std::regex{"[0-9.]*"s}}` and later `d("123 asdf 5.7")`. The idea is to then call d's call operator with `(123, "asdf"s, 5.7)`.